# Dynamically populate listview in jQuery mobile based on if file exists on phone

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

This is the start of my code. It simply populates an unordered list from a JSON file. I tried using the Cordova FileReader without any luck.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("Got deviceready");

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var fileSource = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;

    $.getJSON( "links.json", function( data ) {

            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {

            var $li = $("<li><a href='#'>"+val.title+"</a></li>");

            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

                if(evt.target.result == null) {
                $li.find("a").on("click", function(){ downloadPdf(val.title,val.url); });
                } else {
                $li.find("a").on("click", function(){ openPdf(val.title); });
                }
            };

            // We are going to check if the file exists
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileSource + val.title + ".pdf");

            $("#linkList").append($li);
            $("#linkList").listview('refresh');
            });

    });


}
```

As you can see, this example adds list items with the `downloadPdf(title, url)` function. If it do exists, I want the list item to call the function `openPdf(title)` instead. The files are saved in `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + title + ".pdf"`.

This code doesn't add any items to my list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [file plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) to check if a file exists

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileSource = <here is your file path>

reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

    if(evt.target.result == null) {
       // If you receive a null value the file doesn't exists
    } else {
        // Otherwise the file exists
    }         
};

// We are going to check if the file exists
reader.readAsDataURL(fileSource);
```

Comment: I have tried using FileReader, but it didn't work. Updated question with my code.

Comment: I'm guessing your filepath is incorrect. `fileSource + val.title + ".pdf"` I suppose there should be a slash `/` before file name. Please give an alert to `fileSource + val.title + ".pdf"` and check what you are getting. Also check through file manager if the file really exist in the shown path directory. @janlindso

Comment: Nah, adding a slash give double slash. I tried an alert now, and it returns correct path as I can see: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.helloworld/title.pdf`

Comment: I've tried to do some research and I think there are some security issues that doesn't allow the app to read file from URL.